# columns in the responsive grid system

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying the Responsive Grid System for the first time and having real trouble getting my columns to sit side by side. 
I'm only using a two column grid for some of the design elements and centered content for the rest.

Here's the relevant bit of html:

```
<div class="section group" id="about">
   <div class="col span_1_of_2" id="p1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col span_1_of_2" id="p2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.section {
clear: both;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}

.col {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;}

.span_2_of_2 {
width: 51.8%;}
.span_1_of_2 {
width: 49.2%;}
```

Why are my columns lying in one column instead of side by side? What am I missing?

(you can find the responsive grid [here](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/))

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width problem, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/9C24C/)

`.col` have margin left 1.6% which gives 100% - 1.6% - 1.6% / 2 = 48.4% for `.span_1_of_2` so

```
.span_1_of_2 {
  width: 48.4%;
}
```

---

*Note: This is based on your HTML because you've only used `.span_1_of_2`, in the Fiddle used both spans and set them to this dimension.

Answer (score 0):

51.8 + 49.2 = 101%

Subtract 1 from the first or second.

Answer (score 0):

If I were creating a responsive grid, I would make my `<div>` elements `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and `display: block`. That way, if the columns are small enough they will sit next to each other, but if they become too wide the rightmost `<div>` will go below the other `<div>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZM3bK/